# Can a scrollable DIV update a Range Slider?

Tags: javascript, range, scrollable

I have a range slider that is scrolling the content in a DIV.

If you click on the scrollable area you will see that you can drag the the scrollable DIV to the left and right.  However, when you do this the range is not updated. Is there a way to update the range when the DIV is manually scrolled?  I have tried to get the onscroll() position to update the range with no luck.

https://jsfiddle.net/esoteric/fxtonew7/5/

```
//Range Slider
    var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll-range");
    var panel = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");

    var total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
    var percentage = total * (this.value / 100);
    var percentageWidth = total / 10; //10% for each +/- click

    scroll.oninput = function() {

        panel = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");
        total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
        percentage = total * (this.value / 100);
        panel.scrollLeft = percentage;
    }

    //Foward Arrow
    document.getElementById("increase").addEventListener("click",
        function() {
            scroll.stepUp(10);
            panel.scrollBy(percentageWidth, 0)
        });

    //Back Arrow
    document.getElementById("decrease").addEventListener("click",
        function() {
            scroll.stepUp(-10);
            panel.scrollBy(-percentageWidth, 0)
        });

        
    //Desktop grab and scroll
    const slider = document.getElementById("scrolling-container");
    let isDown = false;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;

    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        isDown = true;
        slider.classList.add('active');
        startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    });

    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isDown = false;
        slider.classList.remove('active');
    });

    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        isDown = false;
        slider.classList.remove('active');
    });

    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        if (!isDown) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
        slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
    });
```

Comment: Both the slider and the left/right buttons seem to work fine for me.  I'm not seeing one behave differently than the other.  What is `the range` you want to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the opposite of what you do for when your drag the slider

```
panel.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=>{
    total = panel.scrollWidth - panel.offsetWidth;
    percentage = panel.scrollLeft / total
    scroll.value = percentage * 100
})
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dwvtLn4g/8/

Comment: Upvote because you would write the lines 100% like i did :)

Comment: @marks :D you added the event on the wrong element though :p

Answer (score 0):

What you would have to do is test wherein the "panel" where you scrolling to and update the scrollbar position

you can do that by adding another panel event listener

```
    panel.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    // get scroll position in px
    console.log(panel.scrollLeft, panel.scrollTop);
    });
```

This will print the left position in the console

Answer (score 0):

Listen for scroll events on your div, then find out how much percent of the scroll was done by dividing the scroll position with the possible max scroll and then set the value (as your range goes from 0 to 100) to that percentage

```
    slider.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
       const maxScrollLeft = slider.scrollWidth - scroll.clientWidth
       const percentage =  slider.scrollLeft / maxScrollLeft
       scroll.value = percentage * 100 // as percentage is normalized from 0 to 1
    })
```